# Paypal payment status, how to get status of that payment again

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

What if i get status pending for a payment at my ipn listener address i.e example.com/ipn.aspx and how i can automate it so when Paypal reviews the payment and cancel/complete it so that i can process the order accordingly.

Do Paypal sends transaction details at ipn again after reviewing? And is there is  a way to test these things in sandbox?

Sorry too many questions but i'm trying for 2 days now, i have used GetTransactionDetails in sandbox, it was working correctly but when i go live its giving permission denied error.

Comment: can you show the error you get when you do `GetTransactionDetails ` in LIVE? are you callng this API on behalf of someone?

Comment: L_ERRORCODE0 : 10007

L_SHORTMESSAGE0 : Permission denied

L_LONGMESSAGE0 : You do not have permission to get the details of this transaction

L_SEVERITYCODE0 : Error

PENDINGREASON : None

REASONCODE : None

Comment: i'm calling it with my api credentials

Comment: do you get any error code(correlation id)? along with `10007`

Comment: this transaction belong to a different account, could not paste the  confidential info here. please ask at www.paypal.com/mts and get me the ticket number, i will look into

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64757/discussion-between-vimal-and-m-qayyum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error usually occurs when the API caller of `GetTransactionDetails` is not
the one who has initiated the original transaction. The owner of the original transaction id has to give permission to the API caller who is making the `GetTransactionDetails` API call.The owner of the transaction id could set permissions [here](https://www.paypal.com/my/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-api-list-auths)

Comment: and then Grant Permission?

Comment: what if i'm the seller and want to check the details of transaction done by a buyer?

Comment: do i need to grant permission to myself?

Comment: this case, you don't need any permission